# How to handle http concurrent requests and rate limiting using rxjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

This application needs to make 100 HTTP requests to an external API. The external API is rate limited.

Below is a working solution of handling rate limit using `RXJS` making use of a map operator to determine if response informed us we were being rate limited (in this case with a 401) and also making use of `retryWhen` if there is an error we delay for 2 seconds and continue.

This works, however if we alter the code from processing 1 HTTP request to now processing 100 or more HTTP requests. The process is handled sequentially and for my `usecase` it's not quick enough.

**Code**

```
const httpRequest = async () => {
  return axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
}

export const httpRequestReactive = async () => {

    const $obserbable = defer(() => from(httpRequest()));

    const result = await $obserbable.pipe(
        map((res) => handleRateLimit(res)),
        retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(2000), take(5))),
    ).toPromise();

    return result;

};


const handleRateLimit = (response) => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log("RATE LIMIT")
        throw response;
    }
    return response;
}

const main = async () => {

  const responseReactive = await httpRequestReactive()

  return responseReactive;

}



main().then((res) => {
  console.log("results: ", res)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("errors:: ", err)
})
```

I know this API is able to handle 25 requests before it is rate limited and then I must await 2 seconds.Therefore, I want to batch the process of requests 25 at a time, this is where I need to handle concurrency, similar to `Promise.all()`.

Below you can see I'veused `mergeAll` https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeAll. Which accepts a concurrency value. *This appears to work.*

**Code (concurrency)**

```
export const httpRequestReactiveConcurrent = async () => {

    const payloads = new Array(100)​.fill({});

    const source$ = from(payloads​.map(x => defer(() => httpRequest()))); 

    const result = await source$.pipe(
        mergeAll(25),
        // tap((res) => console.log(res.status, res.headers)),
        map((res) => handleRateLimit(res)),
        retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
    ).toPromise();


    return result;


};
```

**Problems**:

1. [Solved] thanks to @MoxxiManagarm : `mergeAll` instead of returning an array of results with 100 elements similar to `Promise.all()` I'm left with only 1 HTTP response.

**2. I don't know if my rate limiting works with `mergeAll`. My initial code assumption is that if an individual request is rate limited it should retry that single request. However when I introduce `mergeAll` does the retry occur for every request in the batch if one of the requests is rate limited ( this is what I don't want to happen).**

**UPDATE**

Now that i have an array of responses, upon further testing i can see that im left with more responses in the array than i expect to have. For example im left with 129 response, i expect there to be a maximum of 100 responses. Which makes me believe that mergeAll and my rate limit handler is not working how i would like it to. It appears that its retrying all the requests in the entire batch if one is rate limited?

**I want it to pause whenever it encounters a request that is rate limited, retry that individual request and then continue the rest of the requests in the batch.**

---

**Please see the following stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g9ix8p?file=index.ts (unfortunately i could not find a dummy/placeholder api that has an endpoint which is rate limited)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `toArray()` operator at the end of your stream.

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-udqzbd?file=index.ts

Comment: Great that does give me an array of responses. i'm now left with my second problem of handling rate limiting with mergeAll.